# Why are major keys traditionally happy and minor keys traditionally sad?

Tags: classical-music, history

From the 15th to 18th of last July, I was in a music education camp in Alpensia Resort of Pyeongchang. On the 17th, a masterclass teacher taught this to me and all of the other students, while working on the analysis of Schumann's *Widmung*.

> In a lot of styles of music, we have a nearly-universal tradition that **major = "happy"** and **minor = "sad".**
>
> For example, in Schumann's *Widmung*,
>
> Schumann uses **major** quality when the lyrics go "You my **joy**", and then he uses **minor** quality in "O you my **sadness.**"
>
> [image: Major = happy, minor = sad]

**So, why is it traditional that major is "happy" while minor is "sad"?**

Comment: Of course this is a pretty well-established convention (heavily culture-dependent), but I fail to see, how it has *significance* or even *historical significance*. I'm pretty sure, that there are counter-examples. Without a song text to consider the categorization of the mood can become demanding and I can't imagine, that  composers considered it as a strict rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are applying ourselves to the tradition that "major = happy" while "minor = sad", then here are the "reasons":

> If two wavelengths of one sound line up with three wavelengths of another, the sounds are a fifth apart. If it's 3:4, it's a fourth. These sounds are still harmonious to us even though not as much as the octave sound. This is why they are 'perfect fifths' and 'perfect fourths'.  4:5 gives us a major third, 5:6 gives us a minor third, 6:7 gives us something between a minor third and a major second (which we usually approximate to a minor third) and 7:8 does the same (which we usually approximate to a major second). Beyond that the intervals are no longer really harmonious enough for our ears to pick them up, and they just sound clashy.  So because a minor third is more clashy than a major third, we perceive it as a little more off and this can translate into sad. [source: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1l1qvi]eli5_why_does_a_major_chord_sound_happy_while_a/)]

Furthermore, the harmonic ratios of a major triad is 4:5:6, while 10:12:15 is for a minor triad.  In a major key, the tonic triad is a major triad, while in a minor key, the tonic triad is minor.

Therefore, during the old days, it was interpreted as major keys were "happy", while minor keys were "sad."  However, this has been rendered obsolete; therefore, this is rather based on people's opinions today, and are in fact not universal at all.